# Cannot print numbers after 9

Tags: java, arrays, char, int

I have an char[][]. I want to be printing numbers from 0 untill size. When i reach number 9 then the next character in the ascii table appears. My code is :

```
 if (j >3 && j % 5 == 0 && i==0) {
     bor[i][j] = (char)(co + '0');
     co++;
 }
 if (j == 0 &&  i > 0 && i%2 ==0) {
     bor[i][j] = (char)(ro + '0');
     ro++;
 }
```

the if statement just declares in what position to print the certain numbers.
I guess the way i am converting from int to char is wrong but i do not know any method that would work
after 9.

[image: the error in the table]

Comment: Please take a look at how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "10" is the same as a "1" followed by a "0", so I'd imagine you'd want to be putting two chars into adjacent locations in that case, rather than one.

Comment: There's too much stuff in your code that we don't know about. It makes it very hard to answer. For example, maybe your print is wrong? As above mentioned, please read how to make a good question / example

Comment: I bet as soon as you take a look at a ASCII table you'll understand at least *why* this is happening. Also, is there any reason you're using `char`s and not actual numbers?

Comment: What *single* `char` value would you expect to print the 2-character text `10`?

Comment: wouldn't setting `co` and `ro` String value do the trick instead of adding their value to `'0'`? (assuming `co`and `ro`are integers)

Answer (score 1):

The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character.

Have a look at the code:

```
char ch1 = 67; // it is symbol code
char ch2 = 'C'; // symbol
System.out.println(ch1 + "  " + ch2 );
```

Output is

> C  C

Therefore, you could change type of array from char[][] to int[][], 
and remove casting.

There are a lot of missed code in your example so I will paste not completed example :

```
    int[][] bor = new int[100][100];
    ...
    if (j >3 && j % 5 == 0 && i==0) {
        bor[i][j] = co;
        co++;
    }
    if (j == 0 &&  i > 0 && i%2 ==0) {
        bor[i][j] = ro;
        ro++;
    }
```